# Flutter - Strange pixelated glow around images only on web

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I'm getting a pixelated glow around any png image that I place on the page (the page has a gradient background), only on web:

[image]

Looks fine on iOS and Android.

code:

```
Center(
child: Container(
    height: maxHeight(sizingInformation),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
      image: Assets.images.logo.image().image,
      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
    )))),
```

I get the same issue with this code:

```
Center(
    child: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("assets/logo.png"),
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            )))),
```

Any idea why web is behaving this way?

Comment: Try checking your image and its quality

Answer (score 2):

Try html kit renderer

```dart
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html
flutter build web --web-renderer html
```

Comment: Thank you. I think canvaskit is better in other ways though, so it is not really what I want to do to fix it.

Comment: Change the boxfit to cover or contain and try without specifying the renderer

Comment: No luck there, but thanks.

Comment: Try increasing the quality of image asset. Like if it's from figma. Download the 2x or 3x version of it

Comment: did you find a solution? im having the exact same problem with iamge in flutter web

Comment: The only way I could find to get scaled images to not look pixelated with canvaskit was to make the source images the exact size needed on the screen. I think whatever algorithm canvaskit uses to upscale or downscale images produces jagged edges (like its not using antialiasing)